# What is getting referred in first "it"?

Tags: meaning

In Comedy-Fantasy movie *Death Becomes Her (1992*), Lisle Von catch Madeline's hand and said this words:

> So warm, so full of life. And already **it** ebbs away from you. This
>   is life's ultimate cruelty. It offers us the taste of youth and
>   vitality and then makes us witness our own decay.

There are two **it** are there in above sentence, I want to know what is the meaning
of first "it"?

Comment: Could you explain your difficulty determining what *it* stands for? It is easy to say, but that's not learning. Consider what has a quality that could be described as "ebb and flow".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your context the first **it** can only refer to either *life* or *hand*.
You would need to know that people may refer to

> *life* slipping away

and therefore it can *ebb*, but a hand can not *ebb*. She later refers to

> *life's* ultimate cruelty... vitality... [which then] decays